# Drag&Drop from Edge extension

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

We are trying to develop an Edge extension, and the main goal of the extension is to drag and drop some HTML elements like images. Seems imposible to drop something outside of extension container (appear a restriction icon on element).

To be more specific this extension must works like a drag and drop from tab to another.

Are there any restrictions that can be overriden from Group policies or something similar ?

Thank you!

Comment: Not much clear about your question, can this be done in chrome extension?

Comment: Yes of course, work pretty well in chrome, below are two screenshots with Chrome extension and Edge http://imgur.com/a/Q4x0Z , http://imgur.com/a/5hWMY

Comment: Do you have a test extension I can have a try?